# Why is any positive martingale the exponential of an Ito integral w.r.t. Brownian motion?

Tags: probability, brownian-motion, martingales

> For any positive P-martingale M, $dM_t = Mt ·1/M_tdM_t$. By Martingale Representation Theorem, $dMt = \Gamma_tdW(t)$ for some adapted process $\Gamma_t$. So $dM_t = M_t(\Gamma_t/M_t)dW$, i.e. any positive
>   martingale must be the exponential of an integral w.r.t. Brownian motion.

Why is $M$ required to be positive?

Comment: You need it to talk about $1/M_t$.

Comment: @m7e What do you mean?

Comment: @m7e what do you mean by talk about 1/Mt?